# Using exception mechanism instead of "if" to treat a default object parameter in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Please, look the following excerpt of code:

```
TCustomPoint = class
  private
    //many other fields
    mPoint: TPoint;
  public
    //many other stuff: constructor, destructor, methods, etc.
    function ToPoint(Axis: TAxis = nil);  
end;
```

In the `ToPoint` implementation I want to do something if an Axis object was passed and a different thing if  it wasn't. So the obvious implementation would be:

```
function TCustomPoint.ToPoint(Axis: TAxis = nil): TPoint;
begin
  if Assigned(Axis) then
    Result:=Axis.Reallocate(Self.mPoint);
  else
    Result:=Self.mPoint;
end;
```

but this method will be called over thousands of `TCustomPoint` objects where sometimes an Axis will be passed so I am wondering if I would improve a bit the performance using the exception mechanism instead of `if`. Something like this:

```
function TCustomPoint.ToPoint(Axis: TAxis = nil): TPoint;
begin
  try
    Result:=Axis.Reallocate(Self.mPoint);
  except on
    E: EAccessViolation do Result:=Self.mPoint;
end;
```

Look that I just catch an `EAccessViolation` exception so if there was any other type of exception it won't be manage by me so it would be raised as expected. In this example, the only way an `EAccessViolation` exception occur would be accessing the empty Axis object. **Is that correct? Does the second implementation really improve something? Is there any cons?**

Comment: I'm quite sure anything related to exceptions will be orders of magnitude slower than an `if`.

Comment: Note that this will be a hell to debug, as every exception will come up in the debugger - unless you ignore EAccessViolation, which might cause other problems.

Comment: Whether performance is better is largely down to the compiler/optimiser, and the best way to check is to try it. I doubt if there will be much if any measurable difference, but if there is any I would expect the if...else mechanism to be more efficient. For me, from a readability/maintenance point of view I prefer if...else too, but that is down to personal preferences I guess. This is just an opinion, not an answer..

Comment: Never mind whether it is faster or not, you've changed the meaning of the code. What if Axis is Assigned but the method call raises an exception? You'll just swallow it. Also, why are you worried about performance of an if statement. Clearly you haven't measured the performance implications. Don't attempt to optimise without measurement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually exceptions slow down your application heavily compared to a simple Assigned check.

Instead you can declare two *overloaded* methods so that the compiler will do the checking for you:

```
function TCustomPoint.ToPoint: TPoint;
begin
  Result:=Self.mPoint;
end;

function TCustomPoint.ToPoint(Axis: TAxis): TPoint;
begin
  Result:=Axis.Reallocate(Self.mPoint);
end;
```

Be aware that this approach will not catch the case where a nil axis is given at runtime, so I suggest to use your first approach for that implementation.

```
function TCustomPoint.ToPoint(Axis: TAxis): TPoint;
begin
  if Assigned(Axis) then
    Result:=Axis.Reallocate(Self.mPoint);
  else
    Result:=Self.mPoint;
end;
```